# .child element with class selected should be on top of other .child elements, each .child is inside .parent element with absolute position

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, z-index

Given the html and css below, is it possible to have a .child with class selected appear on top of other .child elements? I'd like if you can give an answer that would not change html structure and css position property of .child and .parent.
Also would be great to not toggle anything on parent, it is better to toggle child classes or styles, for parent it is better to set it once.

```css
.parent {
    position: absolute;
}
.child {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
 
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child selected"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Greatly appreciate any input, thank you.

Comment: increase the z-index of .selected and make there is no z-index set in .parent

Comment: Can i do z-index: unset; on a parent for that purpose ?

Comment: I think that it doesn't work in my set up..

Comment: z-index:auto not unset. It should work based on the code you gave. If not, share your full code

Comment: It works for me only if I set z-index values on parent. So elements appear on top of others only if I set higher z-index on .parent element. The code is basically this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zqyjn4a2/

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick to this HTML structure you could as example hide all elements (children) and show them only when they are selected.

A better solution would be having the selected class on the parent so then you could just simply give the selected parent a higher z-index.

Here you can find a snippet of how you can toggle the display without touching the HTML

```js
// for demo purpuses
var toggleLayer = function() {
  var next = $('.child.selected').removeClass('selected').closest('.parent').next();
  var element = next.length ? next : $('.parent:first-child');
  element.find('.child').addClass('selected')
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.selected {
 display: block;
}


/* for demo purpuses */
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 120px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child selected">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--- FOR DEMO PURPUSES --->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="toggleLayer()">Toggle layer</button>
```